# How do I create a matching url in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

As a regular expression
You want to apply a match to the url.

/board/product/write.html?board_no=4

Matches the above url.

My current regular expression is as follows.

What's wrong ???

Page path / matches RegEx (ignore case) / (.*)/write.html(.*)board_no=4(.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/  must be escaped with a backslash ()
so your regexp would look like

```
(.)\/write.html(.)board_no=4(.*)
```

Comment: Your answers have been helpful.
Thank you.